# Can a backgroundtask be used to update a LOB universal app?

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp, lob

I have a LOB universal app that I want to check for updates from a web service.
If there is an update I want to force the app to update. Is there a way to get the app to update itself or to use a BackgroundTask to update the app? This app would only be installed on Windows 10 Enterprise. Also this app could be installed from the Windows Store for Business or sideloaded if that makes a difference. We have not chose a delivery method yet. We just have a web service that version needs to be kept in-sync with the run UWP app.

Comment: As I understand you would like to update app each time when there is an update in the Web Service. Is that correct?

Comment: Basically yes, when the web service updates I want to force the UWP app to also update.